# Background-size: cover on body is higher than viewport (even though body is 100% height)

Tags: css, background-image

I want to use a background image in my `body`. The background image should cover the viewport (be the same width and height of the screen). I have the following code, but the background image is displayed taller than the viewport/screen: the bottom of the image extends below the fold. It could be that the background image is not being cropped by the 100% height on the body.

```css
    html {
     height:100%;
        }
    
    body { 
      height:100%;
     background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
     background-position: top left;
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     }
    
    main {
     max-width:80rem;
     height:1000px;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,200,0.5);
     }
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: @vals Noticed your deleted answer, do you know why it behaves like that?

Comment: I believe there is a special case with body background, and I think there is somewhere a question about this, but I haven't been able to find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the reason of this behaviour is this part of the specs:

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for 'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not paint this background again.

So this would be a particular issue with **body**

In this snippet, a *body*-pseudo works fine

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/600/");
  background-position: top left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}

main {
  max-width: 80rem;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: I deleted mine and updated yours, plus 1 ... hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @LGSon Of course I don't mind :-)  But your answer was ok , I didn't want to post mine as an alternative., Just wanted to make clear the problem was a special case around *body*. Anyway, it's fine this way.  ...And thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a min-width and min-height of to body in viewport measurements of 100.

See snippet below

```css
body { 
    height:100%;
    min-width:100vw;
    min-height:100vh;
    background-image:url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnfXp5RSFk2ZfOmIl7EMvUHEW0bzWBowc6NtDFkG3M7r2Xljl2");
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<main>  
</main> 
</body
```

Comment: This does not stop it from being cropped when the height is lower than the image's ratio height .... does that make sense?